# ARCore : how to display world origin or axes in debug mode?

Tags: arcore

Is there a way to display the world origin and X,Y,Z axes in debug mode ? (as with ARKit)

Would be very convenient for debug.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in ARCore. Below is an implementation option. In the example, the object is added to the (0, 0, 0) world position and the axes represent the direction in the world coordinate system.

Kotlin example

```
 // Usage: showAxis(this.arSceneView.scene)
 fun showAxis(parentNode: NodeParent) {
    val axisSize = 0.1f
    val axisRadius = 0.005f

    val rootNode = Node()
    val xNode = Node()
    val yNode = Node()
    val zNode = Node()

    rootNode.addChild(xNode)
    rootNode.addChild(yNode)
    rootNode.addChild(zNode)

    xNode.worldPosition = Vector3(axisSize / 2, 0f, 0f)
    xNode.worldRotation = Quaternion.axisAngle(Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f), 90f)

    yNode.worldPosition = Vector3(0f, axisSize / 2, 0f)

    zNode.worldPosition = Vector3(0f, 0f, axisSize / 2)
    zNode.worldRotation = Quaternion.axisAngle(Vector3(1f, 0f, 0f), 90f)

    MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(context, Color(255f, 0f, 0f))
            .thenAccept { redMat ->
                xNode.renderable = ShapeFactory.makeCylinder(axisRadius, axisSize, Vector3.zero(), redMat)
            }

    MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(context, Color(axisRadius, 255f, 0f))
            .thenAccept { greenMat ->
                yNode.renderable = ShapeFactory.makeCylinder(axisRadius, axisSize, Vector3.zero(), greenMat)
            }

    MaterialFactory.makeOpaqueWithColor(context, Color(0f, 0f, 255f))
            .thenAccept { blueMat ->
                zNode.renderable = ShapeFactory.makeCylinder(axisRadius, axisSize, Vector3.zero(), blueMat)
            }

    parentNode.addChild(rootNode)
}
```

> Red - X; Green - Y; Blue - Z;

[image: AR Core Axis demo]